# Задать время для Ping, отправляемого через IdICMP

Tags: c++, сеть, winsock, ping, icmp

Нужно в отправляемом ping задать время, а с ответа взять данные, чтобы проверить есть в сети ip или нет. Т.к. низкоуровневые функции API (к примеру, встроенные в библиотеку ICMP.DLL) показались сложными. Пока решил остановиться на IdICMP. Подскажите какие библиотеки нужны для IdICMP и может кто даст ссылку на статью как работать с ней (все обращения). Пишу MS VS C++ 2008 Express Edition.
В google не нашел, msdn по ней нет, примеры без #include.

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "conio.h"  
#include <iostream>;  
#include "winsock2.h"  
#include "windows.h"  
#include "locale.h"  

int main()  
{  
  IdIcmpClient1->ReceiveTimeout=1000;  
  IdIcmpClient1->Host="77.88.21.3";  
  IdIcmpClient1->Ping();  
  _getch();  
}
```

Ошибки выдаваемые компилятором:

```
.\2.cpp(13) : error C2065: IdIcmpClient1: необъявленный идентификатор  
.\2.cpp(13) : error C2227: выражение слева от "->ReceiveTimeout" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип  
    тип: 'unknown-type'  
.\2.cpp(14) : error C2065: IdIcmpClient1: необъявленный идентификатор  
.\2.cpp(14) : error C2227: выражение слева от "->Host" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип  
    тип: 'unknown-type'  
.\2.cpp(15) : error C2065: IdIcmpClient1: необъявленный идентификатор  
.\2.cpp(15) : error C2227: выражение слева от "->Ping" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип  
    тип: 'unknown-type'  
2 - ошибок 6, предупреждений 0
```

Comment: Случайно, в поисках инфы по IdIcmp набрел на [исходник ping-а](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=259982) для винды. 

Может быть он пригодиться Вам.

Answer (score 1):

А можно сделать за 10 минут совсем просто.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char buf[100];
  sprintf (buf,"ping %s", av[1]? av[1] : "hashcode.ru");
  FILE *f = popen(buf,"rb");

  while (fgets(buf,100,f)) {
    printf ("buf = [%s]\n", buf);
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  pclose(f);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Осталось посмотреть ping /? для чтения справки о флагах команды ping и отфильтровать читаемые в цикле строки (взять что Вам нужно).

Comment: Тут потоки и не понятно как они связаны с сетью, как уходит ping. Также не понял эти строки
FILE *f = popen(buf,"rb");
pclose(f);
Компилятор выдал, что они не объявлены, значит здесь, как минимум не хватает .h или .lib
Это похоже на запись в файл, но вопрос остается, как уходит это в сеть и как пингуется ip.

Comment: @ananas, у меня в MinGW в Windows все работает


    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode> gcc .\poping.c
    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode> .\a
    buf = [
    ]
    buf = [Обмен пакетами с hashcode.ru [5.9.6.228] с 32 байтами данных:
    ]
    buf = [Ответ от 5.9.6.228: число байт=32 время=59мс TTL=52
    ]
    buf = [Ответ от 5.9.6.228: число байт=32 время=58мс TTL=52
    ... просто все не влезает ...
    buf = [Статистика Ping для 5.9.6.228:
    ]
    buf = [    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    ]
    ........
    End
    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>

Comment: А также см. `man popen`.

Кстати, g++ тоже работает

    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode> g++ .\poping.c
    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode> echo $?
    True
    PS C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>

Как пингуется IP?


Естественно командой ping (той, что Вы запускаете в командной строке).

Comment: avp спасибо за разъяснение. Прочитал man popen стало понятней, не все еще понимаю про потоки, поэтому сразу не понял связь между ping и потоком.
Решил другим способом:IcmpSendEcho [url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx]ссылка[/url]

Вопрос тоже в эту тему, т.к. ping идет на своих портах, получая положительный ping не знаешь открыт ли какой-либо другой порт. С помощью чего можно пропинговать, например, 80-й порт, чтобы узнать доступен ли он. Способ посылки http-запросов и принятия ответов решил, но может вы посоветуете другой способ, наподобие ping.

Comment: @ananas, в ICMP (похоже, что Вы называете его ping) **нет портов**. Кратко об [ICMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP) можно прочесть, например, в вики. 

А вообще, ping это программа, которая шлет по заданному IP адресу ICMP пакеты с типом 8 (Echo request) и читает ответные ICMP пакеты с типом 0  (Echo reply).

--

Если Вас интересует 80-й порт и протокол TCP, то проще всего создать обычный TCP сокет и просто попытаться соединиться (connect) с ним.

Comment: @avp, да Вы правильно поняли под ping я говорю о ICMP.
Тоже решил использовать winsock2, только не знаю какой запрос нужно отправить в send? И чем установить timeout, чтобы при недоступности ip не ждать долго?

Comment: @ananas,  send *вообще* вызывать не надо. Сам факт успешного соединения говорит о том, что есть сервер, который слушает данный порт.

Вот с timeout-ом в винде, я Вам (к сожалению) помочь не смогу. В \*nix все просто, устанавливаем alarm, ловим сигнал, а connect при получении сигнала прервется. В винде это не работает.

Собственно есть (наверное) 3 варианта.

1. забросить винду и перейти на \*nix.

2. поискать, как делать connect с неблокируемым сокетом и потом ждать в select (там таймаут есть) установления соединения.

3. попробовать connect в новом thread и как-то убить thread по таймауту.